# Light Source + Prism in a closed box --> What happens under movement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, velocity

**Setup:**

I'm interested in the behaviour of light / the breaking of light in a closed system under movement. I'm sorry in advance if this question is a super-simple, but I just couldn't think of a solution:

Let's assume we have a stable and closed box, in which we have a light-source on the right side, an image-sensor on the left side, and a prism somewhere in the middle. The following image should illustrate the setup:

.

[image]

.

**Question:**

Now the question is, what happens if we move the box? Does the image sensor always record the same image, or does movement influences how the light travels inside the box, thus changes the breaking angle of the light with regards to the prism, and thus changes the recorded image?

.

**My thoughts:**

1. There are two options here. First, if we move the box we move every particle simultaneously (and in the same way) inside the box as well. If that's the case, the image sensor should always record the same image, independent of any velocity changes to the box.
2. If we move the box, everything that is fixed to the box moves instantaneously -> e.g. the light source, the walls, the prism and the image sensor. However, everything that is not glued to the box moves with a certain delay -> e.g the photons. Therefore, movement of the box should influence the breaking angle of the light on the prism, thereby changing the image we record.